# Forward bash colors

Tags: bash, colors, ansi-escape

Is there any way to export the colors of an output of a command?

Let's explain it with a small example:

```
ls -alh --color=auto
```

will print the colored contents of the directory, while

```
ls -alh --color=auto | cat
```

won't print some color. What I want to know is a trick or a tool, let's call it `magic`, that restores these commands like `\033[1m`, so that colors are available for latter processing:

```
ls -alh --color=auto | magic | cat
```

or

```
ls -alh --color=auto | magic >> file
```

**Update:**
I'm using `ls` just for this example, but want to know whether there is a general possibility.

Comment: Are you sure use of `| cat` will remove the color in your current shell session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
script outputfile command
```

will do the trick. e.g:

```
script capture.txt ls --color=always
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the color codes are actually part of `ls` output, there is no way to "restore" them (since they are not there in the first place).

But if you use `ls --color=always`, `ls` will output color codes even when used in non-interactive mode.

Comment: Unfortunately `ls` is just an example :-(

Comment: @binfalse All tools that have color output and have interactive mode detection should have a similar parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `ls` is being smart, and detecting when the output isn't going to a terminal. If you want to tell it to be less so, try `ls --color=always`.

> Using color to distinguish file types is disabled both by default and with `--color=never`.  With `--color=auto`, ls emits  color codes only when standard output is connected to a terminal.  The `LS_COLORS` environment variable can change the settings.  Use the `dircolors` command to set it.